# Can eBooks deleted from Kindle Cloud be 'repurchased' for free?

Tags: kindle, amazon

I recently permanently deleted my book from the Kindle Cloud and/or Content Library. I searched online and this is the [information I read on the issue](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201252650).

It says:

> **Important**: After you delete an item from Manage Your Content and
>   Devices, you will no longer have access to re-download the item unless
>   you purchase it again.

**My question was, that since I have already paid for this book at some given point and yet have to repurchase it—will it be free the second time?**

I could try it myself by repurchasing but did not want to charge myself and then hassle by requesting for a refund. Furthermore, knowing that you "own" these books even if a hacker maliciously deletes your Content Library would be comforting.

Since I have had a very good experience with the Amazon Customer Center, perhaps they'd give it for free regardless of stated policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably rather late for this answer, but Amazon customer service reps do have the ability to get back books you've accidentally deleted.

In my case, I was deleting old personal docs, got prompted to log in again, and didn't notice that the dropdown had switched from "Docs" to "Books" until I'd clicked Select All and Delete and wiped out 200 books.

I immediately got on chat with an Amazon CS rep and explained the situation.  He clarified what was deleted and then said

> No worries, I will restore the deleted books from my end.

It took probably 15-20 minutes for him to finish restoring them, and then for them to all show up in my account again, and the "Acquired date" was changed from its original value to today's date.

But the important thing is that the books are back!

Comment: Incidentally, I've noticed some books that used to be in certain categories no longer are.  I suspect that they were among the deleted books, and that a deleted book loses any categories it had even if you manage to get the book undeleted.

Comment: Another even later answer - I had the same issue and Vignesh C.sorted it out for me straight away.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, accidentally deleted all my purchases from Kindle. Got in touch with the customer service, and was informed I would have to purchase each book separately, and then talk to them again to obtain a refund for each. A real pain because I had about a hundred ebooks, some costly.